# How to not standarize target data in scikit learn regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, predict

I am trying to predict future profit data in a dataset of a copper mine enterprise data in csv format.

I read the data:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

I split the data:

```
data_target = data[target].astype(float)
data_used = data.drop(['Periodo', 'utilidad_operativa_dolar'], axis=1)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_used, data_target, test_size=0.4,random_state=33)
```

Create an svr predictor:

```
clf_svr= svm.SVR(kernel='rbf')
```

Standarize the data:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scalerX = StandardScaler().fit(x_train)
scalery = StandardScaler().fit(y_train)

x_train = scalerX.transform(x_train)
y_train = scalery.transform(y_train)
x_test = scalerX.transform(x_test)
y_test = scalery.transform(y_test)

print np.max(x_train), np.min(x_train), np.mean(x_train), np.max(y_train), np.min(y_train), np.mean(y_train)
```

Then predict:

```
y_pred=clf.predict(x_test)
```

And the prediction data is standarized as well. I want the predicted data to be in the original format, how i can do that?

Answer (score 7):

You would want to use the `inverse_transform` method of your y-scaler. Note that you can do all this more concisely using a pipeline, as follows

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVR

pipeline = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('estimator', SVR(kernel="rbf"))])

y_scaler = StandardScaler()
y_train = y_scaler.fit_transform(y_train)
pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = y_scaler.inverse_transform(pipeline.predict(x_test))
```

Many would just scale the target globally and get away without too much overfitting. But you are doing good in not falling for this. AFAIK using a separate scaler for y data as shown in the code is the only way to go.

Comment: Thanks!, i doesn't put my eyes on inverse_transform(), shame on me.

Comment: Is it crucial to scale the targets with a different scaler, which has not been used for the features?

Comment: A scaler that has been fit to the features, assuming there is more than one feature, will error when used to scale one target, because it expects `n_features` dimensionality

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old and the answer was correct at the time, but there is a scikit-learn method of doing this now.

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/compose.html#transforming-target-in-regression

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned already you ought to use `inverse_transform()` method to retrieve original data from its respective transformation applied prior. 
Another point to ponder is, why the need to transform the Target `y_test, y_train` if our intention is to predict for the **Real Target 'y' values**? We might as well have in it in its original state during prediction.

Also (in Python 3.7.3, sklearn 0.20.3), when you standardize single columned rows like `y_test, y_train` like you have done above you inadvertently receive output as an numpy array which won't help in Dataframe operations;

eg:

[image]

When you do specify that your output should resemble a single columned Dataframe, you may encounter more issues;

eg:

[image]
[image]

**SOLUTION**: You will have to explicitly state that your Target Column Name/Index in a **List** using proper subset selection operators (.loc/.iloc).

eg:

[image]

**NOTE:** in live ML projects, Test Data is something that arrives in the future or collected live when your model is ready for tuning during productionizing stage.

A standardized training-test Features set like `X_train, X_test` help in easy comparison of Feature variation from mean as well as useful for **Regularization** and **Principal Component Analysis** techniques which mandate standardization of feature variables.

Comment: How did you figure out the "solution"?

Comment: @paradoxlover I just wanted to ensure that the resulting datastructure is a 'DataFrame', therefore subsetted 'y_train' using pandas .iloc/.loc functions.